# Где лучше хранить админ-панель?

Tags: оптимизация-сайтов

Где лучше хранить админ-панель для сайта?

Если говорить о серьёзном подходие к сайтостроению с использованием `gulp`, то структура файлов сайта будет выглядеть както-так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Поскольку админ-панель - это, по сути, отдельный сайт, то вероятно для неё придется создавать отдельный `myproject`. Стоит ли это делать?

Comment: А кроме галпа используеться еще что-то? Какой-то Фреймворк? Если например Laravel то файлы хранятся там же где и весь сайт и ненадо ничего делить

Comment: Всё, кроме файлов, к которым вы допускаете доступ по прямой ссылке (CSS, JS, изображения, аудио, видео, etc; одним словом — ассетов), нужно хранить под корнем сайта.

Comment: Никакой фрэймворк не использую; всё делаю на HTML, CSS с препроцессингом, JavaScript с jQuery и PHP. Это всё.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

возможно, такая структура подойдет:

```
myproject (app)
    /admin // фронт для админки
    /api // серверный код
    /webside(или frontend) // фронт сайта
    /common // общее для админки и сайта (сюда можно ассеты закинуть)
```

Comment: Благодраю Вас за ответ! Все эти папки пойдут и в dist, да?

Comment: @GurebuBokofu да

Answer (score 2):

Если вы разрабатываете сайт, используя модульный (компонентный) подход, и если вы допускаете вероятность, что компоненты будут пересекаться между проектами, то ассеты админки стоит хранить там же, где и у основного сайта. Допустим, если вы разрабатываете интернет-магазин, то у вас может быть много компонентов, которые будут пересекаться между админкой и основным сайтом. Например, карточки товаров. На основном сайте эти карточки отображаются в каталоге товаров, а в админке - в качестве превью. Подобный подход позволит вам избавиться от повторяющегося кода и оформить админку в похожем на основной сайт стиле. Помимо серьезных компонентов, вы также сможете обезопасить себя от повторения кода при создании таких банальных вещей, как формы, кнопки, иконки и т.д.

Если вы не используете модульность, то есть если ваши компоненты зависят друг от друга, то разделяйте на два проекта.